# Installing Ionic - The term 'ionic' is not recognized

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am having trouble installing node.js and npm on my computer. I am running Windows 10 Pro x64, and using Windows Powershell (admin).

I am running node.js 9.10.1 and npm 5.8.0

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, I installed ionic cordova using the `npm install -g ionic cordova` command. (I don't know what the difference between that and `npm install -g ionic` is, though.)

I tried changing the windows PATH -thing, but I'm not sure if I did it correctly. (In the path-environment-variable I added a path to 'C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\npm' and one to 'Z:\Program\nodejs' where I installed node.js.)

Comment: Have you tried restarting powershell?

Comment: https://blog.ionicframework.com/new-to-the-command-line/ and read this, Ionic does'nt recommend powershell or command prompt. You should install Git for windows

Comment: @RonNabuurs Thank you. Using git bash seems to work! (I was unaware that powershell and command prompt wasn't recommended by Ionic.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Roaming instead of Local. I think that installing with -g should go in Roaming.
C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\npm>